# SQL Joins and Corelated subqueries with column data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am facing an issue in terms of understanding the joins. Lets say for an example we have two tables employee and sales and now I have a query where we have sales of an employee using the id of the employee

```
select e.employeename
,s.city
,SUM(s.sales)
from employee e
left join (select sales,eid from sales) s on s.eid = e.id
group by 1,2
```

I'd like to understand why s.city wasn't showing up? and also would like to understand what is this concept called? Is it co related sub queries on Joins? Please help me down over here.

Comment: That statement will cause an error, because the column `city` that you reference is not in the `SELECT` list of the subquery.

Comment: `left join (select sales,eid from sales) s on s.eid = e.id` can be simplified to `left join sales s on s.eid = e.id`

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe - can I know what is this concept called in SQL and where can I learn more about it in SQL? do You have any resources for the same? It'll really be helpful for me.

Comment: That is called an "outer join". You join with an (uncorrelated) subquery.

Comment: The "sub-select" is referred to as a "derived table" in this context

Comment: Any good references to understand the same? @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: I'd say you can use any decent book on SQL or read the PostgreSQL documentation. There is [a basic tutorial](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-sql.html), an [advanced tutorial](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-advanced.html), something on [scalar subqueries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-SCALAR-SUBQUERIES),  [derived tables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#id-1.5.6.6.5.8.2) and [joins](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#id-1.5.6.6.5.6.2).

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
 e.employeename
,s.city
,SUM(s.sales)
from employee e
left join (select sales,eid,city from sales) s on s.eid = e.id
group by 1,2
```

in the left join above you have to add city as well. The query Imagine `select sales,eid,city from sales` is a table itself and then from this table you are selecting city (your second column `s.city`) this will run error as your table doesn't have a city column yet.

It is much easier to use CTE (common table expressions than CTE's) You can also do the above question as

```
select 
 e.employeename
,s.city
,SUM(s.sales)
from employee e
left join sales as s 
on e.id = s.id 
group by 1,2
```

## here I have added e.id = s.id instead of s.id = e.id it is better to reference the key of the main table first.

you could use CTE (although used when you have to do a lot of referencing but you can see how it works):

```
With staging  as (
    select 
     e.employeename
    ,s.city
    ,s.sales
    from employee e
    left join sales as s 
    on e.id = s.id 
),

sales_stats as ( 

select
    staging.employeename,
    staging.city,
    sum(staging.sales)
from staging
group by 1,2

#here you will select from staging again consider staging as a separate table so you will have to have all the columns in the staging that you want  to use further. Also you will have to reference columns using staging.x 
)

select * from sales_stats
```

-- here you could have combined the steps but I wanted to show you how cte works, Hope this works for you

Comment: So this concept is called the correlated sub-query concept right? Can I have any references to learn on the same? for a better clarity all together.

Comment: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-subquery/ this might help please note you can also use subquery in where clause as well. However, I would say to use CTE mostly when you are dealing with a lot of tables and modifications https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-cte/, If you have liked the answer above please upvote

Comment: So, if I have columns in the subquery and I select a column in main query which is not part of sub query, then the query will fail to run? Can I have a good reference for this, as I unable to understand what exactly is this concept. It is subquery ? Corelated subquery or Derived table?

Comment: yes it will not run since subquery is like a table and if a table doesn't have a column that you are referencing then it will not work. maybe try this hope this helps https://www.w3resource.com/sql/subqueries/corelated-subqueries-using-aliases.php